# Extracting specific urls from a text file using java

Tags: java, regex, text-parsing, web-crawler

I have a text document in which I have a bunch of urls of the form `/courses/......./.../..`
and from among these urls, I only want to extract those urls that are of the form `/courses/.../lecture-notes`. Meaning the urls that begin with `/courses` and ends with `/lecture-notes`.
Would anyone know of a good way to do this with regular expressions or just by string matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one alternative:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("filename.txt"));

String str;
while (null != (str = s.findWithinHorizon("/courses/\\S*/lecture-notes", 0)))
    System.out.println(str);
```

---

Given a `filename.txt` with the content

```
Here /courses/lorem/lecture-notes and
here /courses/ipsum/dolor/lecture-notes perhaps.
```

the above snippet prints

```
/courses/lorem/lecture-notes
/courses/ipsum/dolor/lecture-notes
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have 1 URL per line, could use:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("urls.txt"));
    String urlLine;
    while ((urlLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (urlLine.matches("/courses/.*/lecture-notes")) {
            // use url
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Nothing** in the description precludes processing the urls. This check is within a loop.

Comment: Unless you explain how to traverse a text token by token (or at least line by line) this answer is not complete. (Also, `^` and `$` are not needed when using `matches`.)

Answer (score 1):

The following will **only** return the middle part (ie: exclude `/courses/` and `/lectures-notes/`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/courses/(.*)/lectures-notes");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourStrnig);

if(m.find()).
  return m.group(1) // The "1" here means it'll return the first part of the regex between parethesis.
```